# crm 4.0 crmservice how to connect remote server?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to connect to the server crm in this way:

```cs
CrmService crmService = new CrmService();
crmService.PreAuthenticate = true;
Shareremover.CrmSdk.CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmSdk.CrmAuthenticationToken();
token.AuthenticationType = 0;
token.OrganizationName = Shareremover.Properties.Settings.Default.organization;
crmService.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
crmService.Url = http : //bfitcrm/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx
//crmService.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;   


if(String.Empty != Shareremover.Properties.Settings.Default.login.Trim() && String.Empty != Shareremover.Properties.Settings.Default.password.Trim() && String.Empty != Shareremover.Properties.Settings.Default.domain.Trim())
{
    crmService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Shareremover.Properties.Settings.Default.login,Shareremover.Properties.Settings.Default.password,Shareremover.Properties.Settings.Default.domain);
    crmService.Execute(Rrequest);
}
else
{
    crmService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}
```

in the line

```cs
crmService.Execute(Rrequest);
```

I have the following error:

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Comment: I edited your post, check if the code I highlighted is correct

Comment: I created a new admin user on crm, with my domain credentials and I solved using DefaultCredentials.